# performance consideration when using properties multiple times

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, properties

I am using `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` when formating my strings using `string.format`

To quote [this blog](http://goatly.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!ED869F22AB5C24A8!171.entry)

> This just has the implication that if
>   you are using CurrentCulture a lot, it
>   might be worth reading it into a
>   private variable rather than making
>   lots of calls to
>   CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, otherwise
>   you're using up clock cycles
>   needlessly.

so as per this author

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
string.Format(culture,"{0} some format string","some args");
string.Format(culture,"{0} some format string","some other args");
```

is better than

```
string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,"{0} some format string","some args");
string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,"{0} some format string","some other args");
```

as per MSDN, [CultureInfo.CurrentCulture is a property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx)

Is there a performance penalty associated when accessing a property multiple times ??

Also I did some emperical analysis and my tests show me that using a local variable is more expensive than using the property directly.

```
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

            int count = 100000000;
            watch.Start();
            for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
            {
                string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0} is my name", "ram");
            }


            watch.Stop();
                 //EDIT:Reset watch
                 watch.Reset();


            Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed);
            Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedTicks);


            Console.WriteLine("--------------------");
            var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            watch.Start();
            for (int i=0; i < count; i++)
            {
                string.Format(culture, "{0} is my name", "ram");
            }


            watch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed);
            Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedTicks);
```

Result:

```
00:00:29.6116306
29611
68922550970
--------------------
00:00:27.3578116
27357
63676674390
```

My tests show that using `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` property is better than using local variable (which contradicts with the authors view). Or am I missing something  here ?

Edit:I was not resetting the stopwatch before teh second iteration. hence the difference. resetting stopwatch, updating iteration count and result in this edit

Comment: In your test code you don't reset the Stopwatch. Using the cached reference is actually faster.

Comment: CultureInfo.CurrentCulture isn't cheap, but string.Format is much more costlier.

Comment: Steven, you  are darn right, I was not resetting the stop watch. Why dont you post that as an answer and I will update my post + mark yours as answer. For those who are curious, yes using local variable is faster. A difference of about 2.473 seconds for 100 million iterations !!!

Comment: +1 This is a very interesting question of yours, Ram. To back up your point, I have read somewhere on SO that accessing properties is costier than private immutable members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in your code. In your test code you don't reset the Stopwatch. When you reset the stop watch, you'll see that using the cached reference is actually faster. CultureInfo.CurrentCulture isn't cheap, but string.Format is much more costlier.

Answer (score 7):

The one true reason to rewrite your code to

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
String.Format(culture, "{0} some format string", "some args"); 
String.Format(culture, "{0} some format string", "some other args");
```

from

```
String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0} some format string", "some args");  
String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0} some format string", "some other args");
```

is for readability and maintainability. Now, if you need for some reason to change the culture from `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` to a `CultureInfo` that is loaded via some configuration file or passed in as a method to the parameter you only need to change the code in one place. **Performance is a secondary consideration here and probably does not matter in that this is highly unlikely to be a bottleneck in your code.**

Answer (score 3):

You should only optimize CultureInfo.CurrentCulture into a local variable if a profiler shows it to be a significant problem in your code and also that putting into a local variable makes it faster.  This profile shows neither is true so I would not put it into a local.