# Full if/else statement vs. Conditional Operator

Tags: c#, if-statement, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Benefits of using the conditional ?: (ternary) operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312786/benefits-of-using-the-conditional-ternary-operator)
>   [Is the conditional operator slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259741/is-the-conditional-operator-slow)

Hi all,

I've got a pretty simple question regarding the different if/else statements.

Apart from writing less code, are there any other benefits for using the conditional operator as opposed to the full if/else statement?

Is there a performance increase, less compiled code, or anything else that would benefit me when using it?

Appreciate your help

**Marko**

Comment: Thanks for showing me the duplicates, they didn't come up when I was typing the answer and I guess I was searching for all the wrong things!

Comment: The conditional operator and the if statement compile to exactly the same CIL code: a conditional branch instruction. (Modulo rearrangement because one is an expression and the other a statement.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't focus on *writing* less code... focus on the code you end up with being more *readable*.

Sometimes an `if` statement will be more readable. Sometimes the conditional operator will be more readable. I like the conditional operator in cases where it makes sense, in terms of different ways of calculating one logical value (e.g. a discount, based on the age of a customer). I don't like using it in convoluted ways though - there's nothing wrong with using a full if/else where it makes sense.

It's worth remembering the null-coalescing operator too... so instead of:

```
string shipTo = customer.ShippingAddress != null 
              ? customer.ShippingAddress : customer.BillingAddress;
```

you can use

```
string shipTo = customer.ShippingAddress ?? customer.BillingAddress;
```

Again, it's only useful in certain situations - but in those cases it's really handy.

Comment: Thank you - that's all I needed to know. I've been reading through some code and have found that some developers over-complicate code by using the ternary operator in places where they probably shouldn't have. Will accept in 8 minutes!

Comment: @Marko: Quick note of pedantry, the *name* of the operator is the conditional operator. It's a ternary operator because it has three operands, but that's just a property of the operator rather than a description of it.

Comment: Awesome - thanks @Jon. I'm still waiting for your book to arrive, no doubt I'll have more questions after I've read it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Apart from writing less code, are there any other benefits for using the Ternary operator as opposed to the full if/else statement?

Better readability, in some cases... I think that's all.

> Is there a performance increase, less compiled code, or anyhing else that would benefit me when using it?

No, nothing significant. I think it will usually compile to the same IL anyway...

So eventually, you should only base your choice on readability. When it's more readable to write a full if/else, do it. If it's a very simple ternary expression that is easy to read, go for it.