# Shorthand if then else performance/optimization in php

Tags: php, zend-optimizer, shorthand-if, php-opcode

Talking about PHP, i would like to ask if there is a difference in performance between these two:

```
$name=($IsBoy)?"George":"Mary";
```

vs

```
if($IsBoy)
{
    $name="George";
}
else
{
    $name="Mary";
}
```

- Will these two result to different opcode?
- If yes, Would be any ***theoretical*** difference in performance? (of course ignore the time that these two needs to be read / compiled / interpreted)
- If, yes, then do optimizers like zend optimizer take advantage of this and do any re-arrangements automatically?

p.s. if you believe that my code for the "full-longhand" if-then-else  is too complex, please provide an example of the most basic code and answer on that.

**UPDATE:**

I hoped the question is perfectly clear, but it seems people do not get the message. This question is about the THEORETICAL (...yet real and mesaureable) difference in performance (thats why i applied **bold** and *italic* in ***theoretical***). Please do not answer by saying what programming style is more readable and that this is too nitpicking to worry about performance.

p.s. 2: by giving emphasis to the word theoretical i try to prevent answers of the type "don't worry its not worth the trouble, its just nanoseconds."

Comment: I don't know for any certainty but my guess is that there is no real performance difference between the two and if there is it would be a micro-optimization which you shouldn't worry about.

Comment: You can check this: http://fabien.potencier.org/article/48/the-php-ternary-operator-fast-or-not

Comment: Fabien's article pretty much matches my own observations as well; though it's nice to see an explanation about why

Comment: Doubt it. But even if there is, the difference will be small it won't be worth worrying about.

Comment: @KristianVitozev that article is really informative, thanks!

Comment: Since you're not worried about real performance and only theoretical performance, sounds like this isn't a real question. It's only a theorectical one.

Comment: @PédeLeão i don't understand the point of your comment, also your definition of "real" and your conclusion that this is a question, but not a "real" question (?)

Comment: And I don't understand the point of you question. You might check out the question guidelines where it says, "You should only ask practical, answerable questions..." http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered. You question seems to fail in that regard.

Comment: @PédeLeão it is practical, because it has applications in real life, and is completely answerable. i asked 1) about the produced opcode (this is not something abstract) 2) i asked about mesaurements for the performance (real life measurements) and 3) i asked about the zend optimizer (is this practical enough for you?). if you believe this answer fails you can flag it. i posted code for god's sakes.

Comment: The Zend Optimizer is about improving code in a real way, not just theoretical. When you start talking about the performance results of nanoseconds, you convincing me all the more that your question has no practical purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK this quite interesting

i have did a quick **x debug** test for your tow examples **respectively**

and here what i have got

[image]

[image]

Sure you may have a different result with each refresh put all of them ensure that

**Second method** is better than first **always**

even though with each refresh you may find first method take less time occasionally
but this is something related with PHP core optimization

regarding to Zend optimizer i didn't test that

Answer (score 0):

I often discard if-then-else in benefit of:

```
$name = 'the expected';
if ([expr]) $name = 'the exception';
```

Easy to read, less braces and compact.

Comment: thats pretty nice, i do it too, but its not an answer to my question.

Comment: But, this is less performant since you're making the engine do more steps than necessary.

What I mean by that is your method will always do the following:
1. Set the variable.
2. check a condition
3. Unset the variable
4. Set the new value and type to the variable.

The IF / ELSE condition will have less steps.
1. Check condition, go to either line
2. Unset
3. Set

No 4th step. So, you're saving a bit of processing when setting the first variable. 25% to be exact.

Answer (score -1):

Both normal ifelse statement and a ternary operator have a slight perfomance difference.You can check the below stackoverflow links for more reference

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643137/ternary-operator-vs-the-conventional-if-else-operator-in-c-sharp)