# Why this way of using conditional operator would give better performance than normal if/else

Tags: c#

There are 3 codes which do the same thing, however their performance differS in x64 release.

I guess it is because of **Branch Prediction**. Anyone could elaborate further?

Conditional:  **takes 41 ms**

```
for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
{
    ret = (j * 11 / 3 % 5) + (ret % 11 == 4 ? 2 : 1);
}
```

Normal:       **takes 51 ms**

```
for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
{
    if (ret % 11 == 4)
    {
        ret = 2 + (j * 11 / 3 % 5);
    }
    else
    {
        ret = 1 + (j * 11 / 3 % 5);
    }
}
```

Cached:   **takes 44 ms**

```
for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
{
    var tmp = j * 11 / 3 % 5;
    if (ret % 11 == 4)
    {
        ret = 2 + tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        ret = 1 + tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you measuring? I don’t believe that the differences are significant. In particular, the last two codes should be equal unless the JIT screws up big time.

Comment: could you show the measuring code?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259741/is-the-conditional-operator-slow

Comment: The quick answer to these sorts of questions is often to look at the CIL (or MSIL in old money).

Comment: Just to make sure: you're testing this in Release mode without the debugger attached, right?

Comment: Your samples do not support the title. The first simply offers a larger target for optimization (both compilers).

Comment: @HenkHolterman I know it is a bit inappropriate but I cannot think of a better one. Feel free to edit it if you came up with a better title.

Comment: We could do with knowing not only how you're measuring the code but how often. If you've only run the code once, the timings are hardly likely to be representative - hence my suggestion of looking deeper at the intermediate code.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT 3**
If I go back to the original test with the timing error fixed, I get output similar to this.

> Conditional took 67ms
>
> Normal took 83ms
>
> Cached took 73ms

Which shows that the Ternary/Conditional operator can be marginally faster in a `for` loop. Given the previous finding, that when the logical branch is abstracted out of the loop, the `if` block beats the Ternary/Conditional operator, we can infer that compiler is able to make additional optimizations when the Conditional/Ternary operator is used iteratively, in at least some cases.

It is not clear to me why these optimizations do not apply or, are not applied, to the standard `if` block. The actual differential is fairly minor and, I argue, a moot point.

**EDIT 2**

There is infact a [glaring error in my test code highlighted here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12462418/659190)

The `Stopwatch` is not reset between calls, when I use `Stopwatch.Restart` instead of `Stopwatch.Start` and up the iterations to 1000000000, I get the results

> Conditional took 22404ms
>
> Normal took 21403ms

This is more like the result I was expecting and borne out by the extracted CIL. So the "normal" `if` is in fact marginally faster then the Ternary\Conditional operator, when isolated from surrounding code.

**EDIT**

After my investigations outlined below, I would suggest that when using a logical condition to choose between two constants or literals the Conditional/Ternary operator can be <s>significantly</s> faster than the standard `if` block. <s>In my tests, it was roughly twice as fast.</s>

<s>However I can't quite work out why.</s> The CIL produced by the normal `if` is longer but for both functions the average execution path seems to be six lines, including 3 loads and 1 or 2 jumps<s>, any ideas?</s>.

---

Using this code,

```
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        var conditional = Conditional(10);
        var normal = Normal(10);
        var cached = Cached(10);

        if (new[] { conditional, normal }.Any(x => x != cached))
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        stopwatch.Start();
        conditional = Conditional(10000000);
        stopWatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Conditional took {0}ms", 
            stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        ////stopwatch.Start(); incorrect
        stopwatch.Restart();
        normal = Normal(10000000);
        stopWatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Normal took {0}ms", 
            stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        ////stopwatch.Start(); incorrect
        stopwatch.Restart();
        cached = Cached(10000000);
        stopWatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Cached took {0}ms", 
            stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        if (new[] { conditional, normal }.Any(x => x != cached))
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static int Conditional(int iterations)
    {
        var ret = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < iterations; j++)
        {
            ret = (j * 11 / 3 % 5) + (ret % 11 == 4 ? 2 : 1);
        }

        return ret;
    }

    static int Normal(int iterations)
    {
        var ret = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < iterations; j++)
        {
            if (ret % 11 == 4)
            {
                ret = 2 + (j * 11 / 3 % 5);
            }
            else
            {
                ret = 1 + (j * 11 / 3 % 5);
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }

    static int Cached(int iterations)
    {
        var ret = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < iterations; j++)
        {
            var tmp = j * 11 / 3 % 5;
            if (ret % 11 == 4)
            {
                ret = 2 + tmp;
            }
            else
            {
                ret = 1 + tmp;
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

<s>Compiled in x64 Release Mode, with optimizations, run without a debugger attached. I get this output,</s>

> Conditional took 65ms
>
> Normal took 148ms
>
> Cached took 217ms

and no exception is thrown.

---

Using ILDASM to disassemble the code I can confirm that CIL for the three methods differs, the code for `Conditional` method being somewhat shorter.

---

To really answer the "why" question, I would need to understand the code of the compiler. I would probably need to know why the compiler was written that way.

---

You can break this down <s>even</s> further, so that you actually compare just logical functions and ignore all other activity.

```
static int Conditional(bool condition, int value)
{
    return value + (condition ? 2 : 1);
}

static int Normal(bool condition, int value)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        return 2 + value;
    }

    return 1 + value;
}
```

Which you could iterate with

```
static int Looper(int iterations, Func<bool, int, int> operation)
{
    var ret = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < iterations; j++)
    {
        var condition = ret % 11 == 4;
        var value = ((j * 11) / 3) % 5;
        ret = operation(condition, value);
    }
}
```

This tests still show a performance differential **but, now the other way**, simplified IL below.

```
... Conditional ...
{
     : ldarg.1      // push second arg
     : ldarg.0      // push first arg
     : brtrue.s T   // if first arg is true jump to T
     : ldc.i4.1     // push int32(1)
     : br.s F       // jump to F
    T: ldc.i4.2     // push int32(2)
    F: add          // add either 1 or 2 to second arg
     : ret          // return result
}

... Normal ...
{
     : ldarg.0      // push first arg
     : brfalse.s F  // if first arg is false jump to F
     : ldc.i4.2     // push int32(2)
     : ldarg.1      // push second arg
     : add          // add second arg to 2
     : ret          // return result
    F: ldc.i4.1     // push int32(1)
     : ldarg.1      // push second arg
     : add          // add second arg to 1
     : ret          // return result
}
```

Comment: When you're interested in speed and optimizations, IL is at most half the story.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, Indeed, it seems so, I moved to a more specific question to see if anyone has the other half. http://stackoverflow.com/q/12462418/659190

Comment: @HenkHolterman Agreed - it certainly wouldn't be your first choice. However, when you have 2 trivial chunks of code that you believe should do the same thing behind the scenes, this is often your first port of call. As a case in point, check out the seemingly harmless setting of a integer value type to zero...

Comment: Hi did u recheck the speed of the original code other than the modified code which "put the functionality for loop into a function"? Do a little math to fix the stopwatcher 65 148 217 -> 65 83 69 is exactly what I got in my question

Comment: @colinfang, I did, I've updated my answer and yes in one way, I have reinforced your question.

Answer (score 1):

> There are 3 codes which do the same thing, however their performance differs

That's not so surprising, is it? Write things a little bit different and you get different timings.

> I guess it is because of Branch Prediction.

That could explain, for a part, why the first snippet is faster. But notice that `?:` is still branching.
The other thing to note is that it is simply 1 large expression, the ideal territory for an optimizer.

The problem is that you cannot look at code like this and conclude that a certain operator is faster/slower. The surrounding code matters at least as much.