# Why does the conditional (ternary) operator seem significantly faster?

Tags: c#, stopwatch

**EDIT**

If I use `Stopwatch` correctly and up the number of iterations by two orders of magnitude I get

> Ternary took 22404ms
>
> Normal took 21403ms

These results are closer to what I was expecting and make me feel all is right with the world (if not with my code.)

The Ternary/Conditional operator is in fact marginally slower.

---

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12457432/659190), which I have partially [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12458395/659190).

I compile this console app in x64 Release Mode, with optimizations on, and run it from the command line without a debugger attached.

```
using System; 
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        var ternary = Looper(10, Ternary);
        var normal = Looper(10, Normal);

        if (ternary != normal)            {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        stopwatch.Start();
        ternary = Looper(10000000, Ternary);
        stopWatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Ternary took {0}ms", 
            stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        stopwatch.Start();
        normal = Looper(10000000, Normal);
        stopWatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Normal took {0}ms", 
            stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        if (ternary != normal)            {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static int Looper(int iterations, Func<bool, int, int> operation)
    {
        var result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            var condition = result % 11 == 4;
            var value = ((i * 11) / 3) % 5;
            result = operation(condition, value);
        }

        return result;
    }

    static int Ternary(bool condition, in value)
    {
        return value + (condition ? 2 : 1);
    }

    static int Normal(int iterations)
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            return = 2 + value;
        }
        
        return = 1 + value;
    }
}
```

I don't get any exceptions and the output to the console is somthing close to,

> Ternary took 107ms
>
> Normal took 230ms

When I break down the CIL for the two logical functions I get this,

```
... Ternary ...
{
     : ldarg.1      // push second arg
     : ldarg.0      // push first arg
     : brtrue.s T   // if first arg is true jump to T
     : ldc.i4.1     // push int32(1)
     : br.s F       // jump to F
    T: ldc.i4.2     // push int32(2)
    F: add          // add either 1 or 2 to second arg
     : ret          // return result
}

... Normal ...
{
     : ldarg.0      // push first arg
     : brfalse.s F  // if first arg is false jump to F
     : ldc.i4.2     // push int32(2)
     : ldarg.1      // push second arg
     : add          // add second arg to 2
     : ret          // return result
    F: ldc.i4.1     // push int32(1)
     : ldarg.1      // push second arg
     : add          // add second arg to 1
     : ret          // return result
}
```

Whilst the `Ternary` CIL is a little shorter, it seems to me that the execution path through the CIL for either function takes 3 loads and 1 or 2 jumps and a return. Why does the `Ternary` function appear to be twice as fast.

I underdtand that, in practice, they are both very quick and indeed, quich enough but, I would like to understand the discrepancy.

Comment: You don't reset the stopwatch between runs. I've never used that class personally, but the docs indicate that the `Start()` method will *resume* timing. I don't think the discrepancy is as great as you think. Try switching the second `Start()` call to `Restart()`.

Comment: You're also measuring the time to call each of the `Func`s?  How does that come into play here?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, you are correct.

Comment: Looking at the others' answers:  To answer my own questions, it doesn't matter about the different methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two take pretty much exactly the same amount of time.

Your results are off because you simply didn’t use `Stopwatch` correctly. The measurement for “Normal” includes the time taken by *both* loopers.

If you change the second

```
stopwatch.Start();
```

to

```
stopwatch.Restart();
```

Then you will get the correct results.

---

By the way, to get a fairer comparison, you should probably execute

```
    return (condition ? value + 2 : value + 1);
```

instead of

```
    return value + (condition ? 2 : 1);
```

so that it is exactly equivalent to the other function. Otherwise you’re measuring *not only* the conditional operator.

Comment: We could however still do with understanding how this was measured in the original question...

Comment: @HenkHolterman Having a consistent way of benchmarking the code is a must. Without this, how can you possibly hope to optimise?

Comment: @RobbieDee - nobody is saying it is easy, useful benchmarking is very hard.